# .gdbinit file missing

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, gdbinit

Eclipse is not debugging my c++ code. It asked for a version of gdb. I fixed the path of gdb but .gdbinit file is still missing. I cant locate it. The debug process just terminates now. Does eclipse has an inbuilt .gdbinit file whose location i can give? Can someone please give me a standard .gdbinit file?

May be its debugging properly but eclipse is not correctly parsing gdb output. Is there a plugin to fix this?

I would greatly appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: What OS? What is the target system of your C++ program (is it your host OS?). Do you have supported compiler/debugger installed in default/usual path?

Comment: @user2058314 : Hi, have you solved your problem please? I am encountering the same thing... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to tell if a) you are having trouble getting Eclipse to find your existing .gdbinit file, or b) you are missing a .gdbinit file.

a) On UNIX and Linux systems, the path to the gdb init file is ~/.gdbinit (or $HOME/.gdbinit) - that is, the .gdbinit file is at the top level of your home directory.

b) A .gdbinit file is not required to run gdb -- even an empty file named .gdbinit will do. For example .gdb init files, check [dotfiles.org](http://www.dotfiles.org/.gdbinit).