# How do I get the .gdbinit command file needed by Eclipse for debugging?

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, gdbinit

My knowledge and experience in programming is still very fresh and basic, so please bear with me.

I want to be able to use C++ on my MacBook (OS 10.9.5 Mavericks) via Eclipse, which I have already been using for Java previously.

So I followed the instructions in [Eclipse GDB MacOSX Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877047/eclipse-gdb-macosx-mavericks)
to get GDB, but now I still need the GDB command file (.gdbinit), which I can't find anywhere (I tried which .gdbinit on Terminal to no avail).

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.gdbinit is a configuration file.  You won't have one unless you've downloaded one or written one separately.  It goes in your home directory and just contains a list of commands to run on startup. You don't necessarily need one.   See this answer: [.gdbinit file missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795407/gdbinit-file-missing)

However, if you are fairly new to programming, I'd suggest starting with Xcode, Clang and LLDB on the Mac for C++ rather than Eclipse, GCC and GDB.   It's far easier to get setup, and well documented.

See:

[How do I set up a C++ project in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282081/how-do-i-set-up-a-c-project-in-xcode-4)

Comment: Thanks for your help!! The debugger does run without the .gdbinit file, but I get some weird error warning messages in the console as it debugs so I thought it might have something to do with the .gdbinit file. I'll give Xcode a try.

Comment: Xcode is definitely an easier starting point.  More coding, less worrying about the tools.  :)

Comment: Very true, I only just installed Xcode and it was really easy to set-up and use. Thanks very much.